# jquery + fadeOut element, addClass (while hidden), re-display element

Tags: jquery, delay, fadein, addclass

I'm looking for some help on achieving the following:

**when document ready ..**

locate and hide a specified div from DOM, while it's faded / display is set to 'none', add a class of 'img2'. After class is appended to initial selector, fade div back in. (display:block)

How can I chain these following methods in **order specified**?

Currently, any 'addClass' method, is initiated as soon as DOM is ready instead of after chained events.

```
/*
select div, 
wait 2 secs., 
fade out for 1, 
add class 'img2' (which changes background-image property / style), 
re-display (display:block) selected element. (#bg-img).
*/
$('#bg-img').delay(2000).fadeOut(1000).addClass('img2');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery.fadeOut supports a callback for code that should be applied after the effect has been completed:

```
$('#bg-img').delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
  $(this).addClass('img2');
});
```

**Update**

As @mdm quite rightly points out, you can pass a callback argument to all of the jQuery animation effects.

Comment: This applies for the other animation methods too - fadeTo, fadeIn, slideToggle, slideUp, and slideDown.

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I'm looking for - (I should have known this.) Thank you for your time. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
$('#bg-img').delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function () {
   $(this).addClass('img2');
 });
```

Comment: Thank you @Fader, as mentioned above, exactly what was needed. Cheers!